# Convert SSRS parameter to Null

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS report that showing Marketing Features. we have in the MF a field called "Test", the values are "PSI 1" or PSI 2" and also the field can be empty.

I added a dataset for the Test parameter with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Corp_Test
  FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[CurrentWorkItemView]
 WHERE ProjectNodeGUID = @ProjectGuid
   AND System_WorkItemType = 'Marketing Feature'
UNION
SELECT 'Null'
ORDER BY Corp_Test
```

Now in the report, the values are `PSI 1` `PSI 2` and `Null`:

[image]

In the Main Query I filtered the results according to the parameter like this:

```
where COALESCE(Corp_Test, 'Null') IN (@TestParam)
```

The report works fine, and if I selected all values I get also Marketing Features with empty Test field.

## My question is:

Instead of `Null` on the dropdown, I want it to be written `No PSI` and actually in the main query it will be Null. is it possible?

Comment: Why not just change your datasource to select `no psi` instead of `null` and then change your `coalesce` to use the same (`coalesce(corp_test,'no psi')`)?

Comment: Works! Thank you!! I totally newbie on SSRS so I didn't understand well what actually the `COALESCE(Corp_Test, 'Null')` doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and easiest way is what @sgeddes answered in his comment.

I just repleced the `where COALESCE(Corp_Test, 'Null') IN (@TestParam)` with `where COALESCE(Corp_Test, 'No PSI') IN (@TestParam)`, and in the dataset I replaced the `SELECT 'Null'` with `SELECT 'No PSI'`.

Answer (score 0):

In your parameter properties, on the `Available Values` screen you will see an option for the `Value` and the `Label`.  This allows you to show one thing to the end user (eg: user friendly description) whilst passing another (eg: key value) to the report.

In your dataset for the test parameter add a column to hold the `Label` of the value you want to pass through to the query.  This can be the same as your `Value` if you so wish, but gives you the flexibility you require on the `Null` entry:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Corp_Test as Value
               ,Corp_Test as Label
  FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[CurrentWorkItemView]
 WHERE ProjectNodeGUID = @ProjectGuid
   AND System_WorkItemType = 'Marketing Feature'
UNION ALL           -- As you have DISTINCT above, UNION ALL will work faster and give the same results as UNION (which removes duplicates)
SELECT 'Null' as Value
      ,'No PSI' as Label
ORDER BY Corp_Test
```

Once you have done this, change your parameter to use the `Value` field as the parameter value and the `Label` field as the label shown to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it can help me in other reports, but the comment of @sgeddes work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
ISNULL(Corp_Test,'No PSI') AS Corp_Test
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Corp_Test
  FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[CurrentWorkItemView]
 WHERE ProjectNodeGUID = @ProjectGuid
   AND System_WorkItemType = 'Marketing Feature'
UNION
SELECT 'Null'
) AS Corp
ORDER BY ISNULL(Corp_Test,'No PSI')
```

Remember to implement the change in your where clause main query. By main query, I mean the query that is feeding your report